# Class.getResource finds resource in wrong jar

Tags: java

- ClassA is located within JarA
- ResourceA is located within JarA
- ResourceB is located within JarB

Both jars are in the classpath.

ResourceA and ResourceB have the same path within their respective jars, ie "resources/somefile.txt"

Using:

`ClassA.class.getResource("resources/somefile.txt");`

I would expect to always get ResourceA however I am getting ResourceB.

Is this expected behaviour, and if so is there any way to garauntee returning ResourceA in this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to classloaders. One trick to overcome such issue is to use something like this:

```
A.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/yourResources")
```

Where A is some class in the desired archive.

Comment: looks like what i'm already doing, unless you mean to put the resource in a different path within the archive to distinguish it from the other archive's resource...